# localStorage en iPad se resetea de vez en cuando

Tags: javascript, html, ios, local-storage

Tengo un juego que he hecho que me guarde unos datos en "localstorage", pero según parece el sistema operativo iOS de vez en cuando hace una limpieza y nunca se sabe cuando será esta limpieza.

Esto es un problema grave para mi juego porque este tiene que funcionar offline sin internet.  Si no hay solución a esto, se me ha ocurrido que podría hacer que el juego me guardara los datos en la app de notas del iPad o en el pages o en el keynote.

¿Alguien tiene una solución mejor a este problema?

El juego tiene un Leaderboard que guarda el top 5 en local y luego en una pantalla oculta el administrador puede ver todos los que han jugado, esa pantalla es una simple tabla: [image: Tabla del leaderboard, versión full]

He hecho que cuando tenga conexión a internet lo pueda mandar por e-mail, solo que no siempre tendrá y quiero que lo pueda guardar en el algún lugar, aunque sea una aplicación de un tercero.

Comment: ¿Podrías dar mas detalle de qué es lo que guardas (imágenes, videos, plist, etc) y quizá un fragmento de código de cómo lo haces y cómo recuperas esos archivos guardados? Creo tener una teoría pero requiero esa información para corroborar.

Comment: Añade la etiqueta HTML JS mejor...

Comment: Gràcies @ArnauCastellví

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tengo un juego que he hecho que me guarde unos datos en "localstorage", pero según parece el sistema operativo ios de vez en cuando hace una limpieza y nunca se sabe cuando será esta limpieza.

Nunca me ha pasado, me parece un poco raro, sin embargo tu aplicación **no debe depender** del localStorage (o sessionStorage), son herramientas muy útiles pero hay varias formas en que puede ser limpiado/eliminado no solo en Safari, sino también el los otros navegadores.

> Esto es un problema grave para mi juego porque este tiene que funcionar offline sin internet. .. se me ha ocurrido que podría hacer que el juego me guardara los datos en la app de notas del iPad o en el pages o en el keynote ...

Desde el navegador No es posible interactuar con otras aplicaciones para leer/escribir datos. Es una cuestión de seguridad. Necesitas otro enfoque.

La opción mas viable seria que usar una mezcla de localStorage y almacenamiento en Internet sincronizando los datos cuando hay conexión, y en el caso de perderse (o limpiarse manualmente) los datos del localStorage, los bajas de la copia en Internet. Claro que en ese momento la webapp debería estar conectada para hacer la descarga ..

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Creo que decididamente después de estas ayudas, lo que haré será cambiar todo mi planteamiento, o implementar alguna de vuestras respuestas. Gràcias por ayudar.

Comment: A ver,,, si lo que guardas en localstorage, es el top 5, que se pierda no es "muy grave", digamos que el funcionamiento del juego no depende de ello. Lo digo, porque depende de la solucion que encuentres, puede resultar como matar moscas a cañonazos, no se si me explico, por ejemplo, si para guardar los datos usa un servidor, ese servidor tendrás que mantenerlo tu, y si deja de funcionar, puede afectar al juego. Evalúa si la solución merece el trabajo.

Answer (score 2):

No hay ningún problema en guardar datos que se queden de forma indefinida y sin que el sistema los borre. Lo importante es guardarlos en la carpeta correcta. A modo de resumen, las carpeta disponibles son:

- `/Documents`: aquí debe ir todos los datos que no se puedan recrear por otros medios o contenido generado por el usuario. *ej: Documento de Word*
- `/Library/Caches`: aquí todo lo que se pueda regenerar sin intervención del usuario. *ej: Cache de imágenes*
- `/tmp`: Archivos temporales para el funcionamiento de la app que deberías desaparecer al cerrar la app.

A partir de aquí, si en tu caso son datos de progreso (por ejemplo) deberías guardarlo en `/Documents` ya que además se hará una copia en `iCloud`.

Tienes más información [aquí](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html).

Comment: Mi juego es en html no lo he especificado, y los datos se generan en un archivo, también html, son esos datos que aparecen en formato tabla en mi documento html que quiero guardar. Con la inclusión de código nativo se podría abrir el Notas o el Pages, eso sería más que suficiente para mi app. La pregunta es ¿se pueden combinar esas dos realidades?, ¿una pagina html ofrecer que se guarde en notas o en pages?